# How is managed current path with _findfirst?

Tags: c++, c, windows

Supposing to use _findfirst in **one** of the two cases below

```
struct _finddata_t  fd;
intptr_t  search_handle;
// Either
search_handle = _findfirst( "file*.txt", &fd );
// Or
search_handle = _findfirst( ".\\file*.txt", &fd );
```

does the two have differences in result?
I didn't find yet if the first form can follow a specific search strategy other that the GetCurrentDirectory() one.

Can it make a difference with some filesystems (like with Unicode special names)?

From what I tested on a few PCs and different versions of Windows, it looked to be the same, but on a remote system that I can't access it looks like there can be some reason for it to fail -- **maybe** when the file name selected is long *enough*, however it's just a supposition I can't prove right now, and I still doubt it exceeds _MAX_PATH.

Comment: It should be the same, there is no reason why it should'nt be. Same thing for e.g. `fopen(".\\file.txt", ...` vs. `fopen("file.txt", ...`

Comment: BTW: I'd rather use `FindFirstFile`, `FindNextFile` etc. instead of `_findfirst`, `_findnext` etc.

Comment: Yes, FindFirstFile, etc. would simplify my (possible) path length issue too, but having that part of code usable with different environments would require me some back and forth translation char/TCHAR. Maybe I'll consider it too, thanks.

Comment: The only issue I can think of is trying to list an NTFS subdirectory with single-letter name using the full stream name. For example, `".\\C:$I30:$INDEX_ALLOCATION\\file*.txt"` looks in the current directory for a directory named "C" and explicitly references its "$I30" index, i.e. the normal directory listing. On the other hand, `"C:$I30:$INDEX_ALLOCATION\\file*.txt"` looks in the working directory on drive "C:" for a directory named "$I30" with a data stream "$INDEX_ALLOCATION", which probably doesn't exist and would be wrong anyway since it's a data stream.

Comment: @LMS, at this point it should just be considered wrong to pass 8-bit `char *` filenames to Windows. The ANSI API is supported for legacy code, but new code should use Unicode. ANSI leads to mojibake nonsense (except for the beta UTF-8 support in Windows 10). If you need 8-bit strings for other reasons, then manually implement UTF-8 to UTF-16LE translation, and call `FindFirstFileW`.

Comment: @eryksun, that about NTFS is quite interesting as I didn't know about this representation, thanks.

Comment: See [file streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/file-streams), which briefly discusses a similar ambiguity with single-letter filenames such as "C:streamname", which has to be accessed via either the fully-qualified path or the explicit relative path `".\\C:streamname"`.